# DT::renderTable() displays 'No matching records found' and 'Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from x total entries)'

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am working on a app, where the user can select columns and rows of a dataframe and a transformation method for further analysis. After pressing the 'apply'-button, there should be displayed 3 tables:

1. table with raw data
2. table with selected raw data
3. table with transformed data (not selected columns should be completely excluded from analysis, rows should not be displayed in transformed table).

Unfortunately when altering the columns e.g. from "cyl", "disp", "hp" (3 columns) to "mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat" (5 columns) the tables 2. and 3. would show the 3 column headers and 'No matching records found' where the rows should be displayed and also 'Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from x total entries)' -> so there is no update of the column headers.

Also the callback download button does not work properly. Sometimes it download the html-file or it doesn't show at all.

I put a code example below (simplified as much as possible). Rows are showing as they should. Maybe because there are less datapoints (original dataframe has about 100 x 30 000 data points).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

transformDataFrame <- function(dataFrame, method = "none") {
  transformedSamplesData <- dataFrame[,2:ncol(dataFrame)]
  if(method == "none") {
    # no transformation
  } else if(method == "add1") {
    transformedSamplesData <- transformedSamplesData + 1
  } else if(method == "add2") {
    transformedSamplesData <- transformedSamplesData + 2
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
  dataFrame[,2:ncol(dataFrame)] <- transformedSamplesData
  return(dataFrame)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "selectNormalization", label = "Select normalization",
                  choices = c("none" = "none",
                              "Add 1" = "add1",
                              "Add 2" = "add2"),
                  selected = "none", multiple = F),
      pickerInput(inputId = "selectSamples", label = "Select samples",
                  choices = NULL, selected = "", multiple = TRUE,
                  options = list(`live-search`=TRUE,
                                 `actions-box`=TRUE,
                                 `none-selected-text`="No sample selected",
                                 `selected-text-format`="count",
                                 `count-selected-text`="{0} out of {1} samples")),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectFilter", label = "Select gene filter",
                  choices = c("none" = "none",
                              "Select rows" = "rows"),
                  selected = "none", multiple = F),
      div(actionButton(inputId = "buttonResetFilter", label = "Reset"),
          style="display:inline-block"),
      span(actionButton(inputId = "buttonApplyFilter", label = "Apply"),
                   style = "float:right")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Input data",
                           #style = 'overflow-x: scroll',
                           uiOutput("inputUI")),
                  tabPanel("Filtered raw data",
                           uiOutput("filteredUI")),
                  tabPanel("Transformed data",
                           uiOutput("transformedUI"))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    inputData <- reactive({
      newCars <- data.frame(rownames(mtcars))
      newCars[,2:6] <- data.frame(mtcars[,1:5], row.names = NULL)
      names(newCars) <- c("Name", names(mtcars[,1:5]))
      sampleNames <- names(newCars)[2:ncol(newCars)]
      updatePickerInput(session = session, inputId = "selectSamples",
                        choices = sampleNames, selected = sampleNames)
      return(newCars)
    })

    userSelection <- dataTableProxy('rawTable')

    selectedSamples <- reactive({
      sampleColumns <- which(names(inputData()) %in% input$selectSamples)
      return(sampleColumns)
    })

    selectedRows <- reactive({
      selectedRows <- input$rawTable_rows_selected
      if (length(selectedRows)) {
        return(sort(selectedRows))
      } else {
        return(0)
      }
    })

    selectedGenes <- reactive({
      if(length(input$selectSamples)>0) {
        if (input$selectFilter=="none") {
          numberOfRows <- nrow(inputData())
          return(c(1:numberOfRows))
        } else if (input$selectFilter=="rows" && (!selectedRows()==0)) {
          return(selectedRows())
        }
      } else { # no samples selected || no file uploaded
        return(NULL)
      }
    })

    subsetData <- reactiveValues(rawData = NULL, transformedData = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$buttonApplyFilter, {
      if(length(input$selectSamples)>0 && length(selectedGenes())>0) {
        subsetData$transformedData <- NULL
        selectedSamplesData <- inputData()[,c(1, selectedSamples()), drop = FALSE]
        transformedSamplesData <- transformDataFrame(selectedSamplesData, input$selectNormalization)
        subsetData$rawData <- selectedSamplesData[selectedGenes(), , drop = FALSE]
        subsetData$transformedData <- transformedSamplesData[selectedGenes(), , drop = FALSE]
      } else {# no samples selected || no file uploaded
        subsetData$rawData <- NULL
        subsetData$transformedData <- NULL
        return(NULL)
      }
    })

    output$rawTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(inputData(),
                    extensions=c('Buttons', 'Scroller', 'FixedHeader', 'Responsive', 'ColReorder'),
                    options=list(lengthMenu = c(25, 50, 100),
                                 pageLength=25,
                                 dom='<"row"<"col-sm-4"l><"col-sm-4"B><"col-sm-4"f>>rtip',
                                 buttons=I('colvis'),
                                 fixedHeader=TRUE,
                                 colReorder=list(realtime=FALSE),
                                 scrollY=500))
    })

    output$selectedTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$buttonApplyFilter
      DT::datatable(subsetData$rawData,
                    selection='none',
                    callback=JS("$('div.saveSelected').append($('#downloadSelected'));"),
                    extensions=c('FixedColumns', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'), #'Buttons',
                    options=list(dom='<"row"<"col-sm-8"<"div.saveSelected">><"col-sm-4"f>>rtip',
                                 scrollX=TRUE,
                                 fixedColumns=list(leftColumns=2),
                                 fixedHeader=TRUE,
                                 scrollY=500,
                                 scroller=TRUE))
    })

    output$transformedTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$buttonApplyFilter
      DT::datatable(subsetData$transformedData,
                    selection='none',
                    callback=JS("$('div.saveTransformed').append($('#downloadTransformed'));"),
                    extensions=c('FixedColumns', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'), #'Buttons',
                    options=list(dom='<"row"<"col-sm-8"<"div.saveTransformed">><"col-sm-4"f>>rtip',
                                 scrollX=TRUE,
                                 fixedColumns=list(leftColumns=2),
                                 fixedHeader=TRUE,
                                 scrollY=500,
                                 scroller=TRUE))
    })

    output$inputUI <- renderUI({
        tagList(DT::dataTableOutput("rawTable"))
    })

    output$filteredUI <- renderUI({
        tagList(downloadButton(outputId = "downloadSelected", label = "Save table (selected data)"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("selectedTable"))
    })

    output$transformedUI <- renderUI({
        tagList(downloadButton(outputId = "downloadTransformed", label = "Save table (transformed data)"),
                DT::dataTableOutput("transformedTable"))
    })

    observeEvent(input$buttonResetFilter, {
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectNormalization", label = "Select normalization",
                        choices = c("none" = "none",
                                    "Add 1" = "add1",
                                    "Add 2" = "add2"),
                        selected = "none", multiple = F)
      numberOfCol <- ncol(inputData())
      sampleNames <- names(inputData())[2:numberOfCol]
      updatePickerInput(session = session, inputId = "selectSamples",
                        choices = sampleNames, selected = sampleNames)
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectFilter", label = "Select gene filter",
                        choices = c("none" = "none",
                                    "Select rows" = "rows"),
                        selected = "none", multiple = F)
      userSelection %>% selectRows(NULL)
      subsetData$rawData <- NULL
      subsetData$transformedData <- NULL
    })

    output$downloadSelected <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("data_selection_", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"), ".csv", sep="")},
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(subsetData$rawData, file, row.names=FALSE)},
      contentType = "text/csv"
    )

    output$downloadTransformed <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("data_transformation_", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"), ".csv", sep="")},
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(subsetData$transformedData, file, row.names=FALSE)},
      contentType = "text/csv"
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My first approach was to change reactiveValues$x to `subsetDataX <- reactive({ ... })` but I don't want the values to be computed everytime the user changes an input. Furthermore I tried `replace(proxy, data)`, which didn't have an effect.

I would be very pleased, if somebody has an idea how to solve this or can give me a hint what is wrong.

Thanks in advance! Vivienne